# ClusterManager setOnCameraIdleListener

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2, android-maps-utils

While trying to implement use `ClusterManager`, I noticed that the `getMap().setOnCameraChangeListener(clusterManager)` is deprecated. Looking at the android-maps-utils sample on Github, I noticed that `getMap().setOnCameraIdleListener(mClusterManager);`

When I try doing the same, I get an error because the default `ClusterManager` class doesn't implement `GoogleMap.OnCameraIdleListener`.

Yet, in my gradle file, I am using what seems to me, the latest maps-util libraries:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.4.3'
}
```

How can I get access to the newest `ClusterManager` class?
Thanks

Answer (score 20, accepted):

instead of:

```
mMap.setOnCameraChangeListener(mClusterManager);
```

do that:

```
final CameraPosition[] mPreviousCameraPosition = {null};
    googleMap.setOnCameraIdleListener(new GoogleMap.OnCameraIdleListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCameraIdle() {
            CameraPosition position = googleMap.getCameraPosition();
            if(mPreviousCameraPosition[0] == null || mPreviousCameraPosition[0].zoom != position.zoom) {
                mPreviousCameraPosition[0] = googleMap.getCameraPosition();
                clusterManager.cluster();
            }
        }
    });
```

that will work...

Comment: how we do same thing for setOnCameraMoveStartedListener in cluster manager?

Answer (score 0):

after  play-services-maps 9.4.0 version of the API they change GoogleMap.OnCameraChangeListener to this 3 listeners

GoogleMap.OnCameraMoveStartedListener,

GoogleMap.OnCameraMoveListener,

GoogleMap.OnCameraIdleListener.